# Probability of having 3 king cards separated in a hand of 5

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Suppose I have 5 cards, 3 of them are kings and other are 2 queens. I lay them down side by side.

What's the probability of those 3 king cards not being together?

Here's what I did (supposedly incorrect):

- 5! = 120 possible combinations
- P<sub>king</sub> * P<sub>suits</sub> * 3! <-- (Possible positions occupied by the kings)

  = 3! * 2! * 3!

  = 72 favorable cases
- 72 / 120 = 6/10 = 0.6

According to my book, this answer seems to be incorrect. Where have I gone wrong? Thanks.

### EDIT: My bad guys, should've specified No king is adjacent to another king. p.e KK2K2 is not acceptable.

Comment: Not sure what '"not being together means".  is $KK23K$ acceptable?

Comment: "*And other 2 are* **suits**"  In a deck of cards... each card has two pieces of information to distinguish it.  You have the *ranks* $2,3,4,5,\dots,10,J,Q,K,A$,  and then you have the *suits* $\heartsuit,\diamondsuit,\spadesuit,\clubsuit$, so for example you have the ace of spades ($A\spadesuit$).  Your question as written does not make sense, but could be made better by changing the word "suits" to something else.  For example, "Suppose I have 5 cards, 3 of them are kings and other two are *queens*"  having replaced the word "suits" for instead a rank different than king.

Comment: As for how to phrase "not being together" so as to imply unambiguously that `KK2K2` is not acceptable., I would recommend the phrase "*No king is adjacent to another king*"

Comment: @JMoravitz I have edited the question, thank you for pointing it out. I had placed the exact word my book gave me, I was confused for the first time too :)

Answer (score 1):

If "not being together" also means that two of the kings can't be together, then the answer should be 
$$\frac{3!\cdot 2!}{5!} = \frac{1}{10}$$
because when there is no king together with another, there is only one placement of the cards, which is $KSKSK$ where $K$ stands for king and $S$ stands for suit. Then $K$'s can switch places among themselves with $3!$ and so $S$'s do with $2!$. Then the result follows.